# How to get the nth element of @rest in Less?

Tags: less

I'm writing a Less mixin.

I want to be able to pass the mixin several(undefined) parameters and get the params one by one.

```
.my-mixin-with-property(@property, @value-1, @value-2, ...) {
    @{property}: some-func(@value-1) some-func(@value-2) ...;
}
```

I am going to use `@rest` and then pass undefined numbers of parameters but I don't know how to get the elements of `@rest` one by one, so I can pass the elements to `some-func` one by one and get the result.

How to do this? Thanks!

Comment: first of all name it, e.g. `.m(@property, @value-1, @value-2, @name-for-the-rest...)`, then the use [corresponding function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions).

Comment: Assuming *so I can pass the elements to some-func one by one* the most fitting example for your use-case would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013528 - *part 3* I guess (find more by strating with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954762)

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.