# LESS ParseError: Unrecognised input

Tags: css, compilation, less

I am getting an error when I compile this code here with WINLess:

```
.icon-text-shadow (@icon-text-shadow: 0.0625rem 0.0625rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1), 0.125rem 0.125rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1);) {
    box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
    -moz-box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
}
```

The error is:

> ParseError: Unrecognised input in PATH\file.less on line 34, column
>   126

The column 126 is between the last ) and the first {
I am rather new at this but I have searched everywhere and got no clue still what is wrong.

Thank you for any suggestions..

Comment: This may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231369/how-do-you-create-multiple-box-shadow-values-in-less-css?rq=1

Comment: With Hex colors works fine it seems..

Comment: Seems like a compiler problem/bug but putting it within quotes and escaping should work - `@icon-text-shadow: ~"0.0625rem 0.0625rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1), 0.125rem 0.125rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1)"` like [here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.icon-text-shadow%20(%40icon-text-shadow%3A%20~%5C%220.0625rem%200.0625rem%20rgba(132%2C%20108%2C%20172%2C%201)%2C%200.125rem%200.125rem%20rgba(132%2C%20108%2C%20172%2C%201)%5C%22)%20%7B%5Cnbox-shadow%3A%20%40icon-text-shadow%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cna%7B.icon-text-shadow()%3B%7D%22%7D). I've avoided the prefixes but that wouldn't cause any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just found an issue with the compiler.

Your code is perfectly fine and should work as expected. The culprit is the second `rgba(132, 108, 172, 1)`. Delete that and it will work.

I played around a bit and it seems that this always happens when there is a comma separated list as parameter and any element of that list, that is not the first, contains a function call.

Workaround in Aureliano's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that must be a problem with the enumeration. Try this:

```
@icon-text-shadow-default: 0.0625rem 0.0625rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1), 0.125rem 0.125rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1);
.icon-text-shadow (@icon-text-shadow: @icon-text-shadow-default) {
    box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
    -moz-box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
    -webkit-box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to parsing a string separated by commas without [escaping](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) it.

Try this:

```
.icon-text-shadow (@icon-text-shadow: ~"0.0625rem 0.0625rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1), 0.125rem 0.125rem rgba(132, 108, 172, 1)") {
    box-shadow: @icon-text-shadow;
}
```

**Note:** There's no need to use vendor prefixes for `box-shadow` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Check file encoding. If it "UTF-8 with BOM" then LESS can't directly build it. Change encoding to plain UTF-8.